# R Error Wilcoxon Test in for loop over columns of data frame: not enough (finite) 'x' observations

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

I have a data frame of dim 15 x 555 of row-wise sample numbers against column-wise protein names. The last 3 columns of this data frame hold mapping information ie Treatment, Treatment_Time, and Month and are labeled as such.

While looping over the data frame column wise, I was hoping to conduct wilcoxon tests using wilcoxon.test and grabbing information from the df directly based on the mapping information.

rough ex:

```
pre_post <- vector()
for(i in names(df[,1:552])){  
    pre_post <- append(pre_post, wilcox.test(df[df$Treatment_Time %in% "Pre", i], df[df$Treatment_Time %in% "Post", i], na.action(na.omit))$p.value))}
```

The expectation is to have a vector with p values of wilxcoxon tests of length 552. If the wilcoxon test cannot be completed as anticipated, I hope to input and "NA".

This script works until a particular column doesn't have a value for a subset of data like Post and then delivers the aforementioned error. I've tried combating this with if else statements regarding the length of the subset of data in a column for a test but I can't get it to work.

```
for(i in names(df[,1:552])){
    if(length(df[df$Treatment_Time %in% "Pre", i])>1 & length(df[df$Treatment_Time %in% "Post", i])>1){
        pre_post <- append(pre_post, wilcox.test(df[df$Treatment_Time %in% "Pre", i], df[df$Treatment_Time %in% "Post", i], na.action(na.omit))$p.value)
    }
    else{     
    all_amb_all_delay <- append(all_amb_all_delay, "NA")
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What do you want to happen in the case where such values don't exist?

Comment: Your code produces no results regardless since the implicit call to `print()` does not happen within a loop. You need to explicitly use the `print()` function or add the values to a vector to preserve the results. Look at the difference between `for (i in 1:5) 1 + i` and `for (i in 1:5) print(1 + i)`.Your code will also be simpler if you use the formula method for `wilcox.test()`. Read the manual pages: `?Control` and `?wilcox.test`.

Answer (score 3):

Consider `tryCatch` to return NA on filters with zero rows resulting in error of `wilcox.test`. Below uses `sapply` to return p values in a vector.

```
p_value_vector <- sapply(names(df[,1:552]), function(i) 
    tryCatch(
      wilcox.test(df[df$Treatment_Time %in% "Pre", i], 
                  df[df$Treatment_Time %in% "Post", i], 
                  na.action(na.omit))$p.value),
      warning = function(w) return(NA),
      error = function (e) return(NA)
    )
)
```